# D Binding Generation Tool

Tags: c, header, wrapper, d, auto-generate

Is there a tool to automatically create D bindings from C headers? I've hade some problems with obselete D wrappers on github and it would be great to have a tool do all the manual work for me and also assure that my bindings are up-to-date.

Answer (score 5):

There is also [dstep](https://github.com/jacob-carlborg/dstep) by Jacob Carlborg which uses LLVM to provide the header conversion.

Answer (score 2):

[htod](http://dlang.org/htod.html) is available from the dlang website

Comment: You should note that `htod` is Windows only.

Comment: It also looks rather outdated to me, have never had a single real-world header that "just worked" after conversion with it.

Answer (score 0):

See this thread:

http://forum.dlang.org/thread/mfkesujhjrcqlxxrhmtl@forum.dlang.org?page=1

There's 'dstep'.

'swig' (quite likely the best choice).

'mkconfig' at http://gentoo.com/di/mkconfig.html